# Free infinitary algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, universal-algebra, infinitary-combinatorics

Let $\Sigma$ be a set which consists of function symbols with allowed infinite arities (which can be arbitrary sets). A $\Sigma$-algebra is a set $X$ equipped with maps $\omega_* : X^d \to X$ for each function symbol $\omega \in \Sigma$ of arity $d$. We have a category of $\Sigma$-algebras with a forgetful functor to the category of sets.

**Question.** What is a reference for the construction of free $\Sigma$-algebras?

Nowadays it seems to be quite popular to define algebraic theories in such a way that free algebras are already included, more or less, into the definition. This is not the case with the definition above. Of course, the classical case is when the arities are finite sets. In this case, it is quite clear what to do. One defines terms of a given height inductively. A term of height $0$ is one of the chosen generators, and a term of height $\alpha+1$ is a function symbol paired with a family of terms of height $\leq \alpha$ (but at least one of height $\alpha$) indexed by the arity. If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, do we define a term of height $\alpha$ as a function symbol paired with a family of terms of unbounded heights $<\alpha$ indexed by the arity? Then, if $\alpha$ has cofinality larger than all arities, there is no such family and therefore there will be no term of height $\alpha$, and hence also no term of height $\geq \alpha$. Hence, the coproduct of all the sets of terms of a given height is well-defined, and I guess that this is the underlying set of the free $\Sigma$-algebra. Is this correct? References to the literature are highly appreciated.

Comment: Why "at least one of height $\alpha$"?

Comment: I want the height to be well-defined. For example, a typical term of height $2$ in the theory of magmas is $x \cdot (x \cdot y)$, but $x \cdot y$ is not of height $2$ (although it is a product of elements of height $\leq 1$); it is of height $1$.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help, but have you taken a look at Cohn's book? https://www.amazon.com/Universal-Algebra-Mathematics-Its-Applications/dp/9027712549

Comment: @EricAuld: I don't have a copy of this book.

Comment: Might be worth getting it from the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attempt to define free algebras in the same way. It is the usual practice, as your first paragraph seems to suggest, to let the arities be cardinals, not ordinals, as you assume later on. Then if $A$ is a set of terms of cardinality $\beta$ and $f$ is a function symbol of arity $\beta$, we say the symbol $fA$ has rank the greater of $\beta$ and the supremum of ranks of terms $a\in A$. This disagrees mildly with your conventions.

The problem is that the class of terms so produced may not be a set. In fact, explicit examples have been known since 1964, most famously the free complete lattice on three generators. References include the wikipedia article on free lattices and its references, including Johnstone's Stone Spaces do [this article,](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm54/fm5416.pdf) the link to which might not work.

Comment: To be clear, the terms can only fail to form a set if $\Sigma$ is not a set (e.g., because it includes operations of arbitrary arity).  If $\Sigma$ is a set, then as indicated in the question you will stop getting new terms as soon as you hit a limit ordinal of cofinality greater than the arities of all your operations.

Comment: Thanks. "This disagrees mildly with your conventions." Can you be more specific here? Is my approach wrong? As for the second paragraph, Eric has explained correctly that these issues do not appear here.

Comment: @HeinrichD Sure, it wasn't really clear to me that you had required $\Sigma$ be a set. There are also theories with a proper class for a signature that do admit free algebras. To be more specific, my ranks are cardinals and yours are ordinals; your function symbols all uniformly increase the rank by 1, whereas I consider a function of large arity to produce high-rank terms; I thus don't need the extra condition about plugging in some term of rank $\alpha$.  I think your construction still works, though.

Comment: Thank you. I've also clarified in my post that $\Sigma$ is a set (this is satisfied in my application).